# Why is one global var updating and the other is not?

Tags: python

```
dum = ['flower','show', 'bl']
longestStore = []
max_len = 0

def longestCommonPrefix(strs):

    strs_size = len(strs)
    for i in range(strs_size):
        longestStore.insert(i, len(strs[i]))
    max_len = max(longestStore)

longestCommonPrefix(dum)
print(longestStore)
print(max_len)
```

The results of `print(longestStore)` is `6,4,2` as I would expect, but
printing `max_len` gives a result of zero. I am confused here because the information inside the method is being saved into global variable `longestStore` since it updates correctly as `6,4,2`. However, when it comes to `max_len` which is declared outside of the method, it never seems to update and stays as zero. I don't understand how this could be the case.

Comment: Mandatory link to [Ned Batchelder](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Comment: When you assign to `max_len`, you are creating a new *local* variable, not assigning to the existing global variable of the same name. This is what the `global` statement is for.

Comment: And as an aside, you shouldn't be trying to use global variables like this here to begin with. But yes, read [this](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Comment: And it's very important to understand, *python doesn't have variable declarations*. Variables spring into existence *when they are assigned to*. By default, *all assignments are local*

Answer (score 3):

You are mutating `longestStore` by using the `insert()` method, but you are assigning a value to `max_len` without having declared it `global` first, which means the scope of `max_len` is entirely within your function `longestCommonPrefix()`, that is it goes out of scope when you exit.

So,`longestStore` is recognised as global by default, because you never assign to it. On the other hand `max_len` is assumed to be local because you *do* assign to it and haven't declared it `global`.

Comment: longestStore and max_len are both declared outside of the scope of the function. It recognizes that for longestStore but not for max_len? Can you explain that a little bit more for me please? I get that i'm mutating longestStore but why can it recognize longestStore as global and not max_len as global ?

Comment: @jojo33 Any name that you assign to inside a function is assumed to be local to that function unless there is a `global` statement. You assign to `max_len` inside the function, but you don't assign to `longestStore`, you only update its contents.

Comment: Hi khelwood, is it a coding standard to always put global in front of whatever you are updating inside your function as well?

Comment: As a programmer you should try very, *very*, **very** hard not to use globals.

Comment: You use `global` if what you want to assign to is a global variable. It's about *correctness*, not what is standard.

Comment: @jojo33 **no**. You **shouldn't be using global variables like this at all**. Mutable, global state is an anti-pattern

Comment: I see, I will take that much more seriously then.

Answer (score 0):

Declare `longestStore` in the function and make it and `max_len` the returns from the function.

```py
dum = ['flower','show', 'bl']

def longestCommonPrefix(strs):
  longestStore = []
  strs_size = len(strs)
  for i in range(strs_size):
      longestStore.insert(i, len(strs[i]))
  max_len = max(longestStore)

  return longestStore, max_len
  
my_longestStore, my_max_len = longestCommonPrefix(dum)
  
print(my_longestStore)
print(my_max_len)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use global variables, since they lead to unexpected behavior.
Use `return` to get results back from a function.

```
def longest_common_prefix(strings):
    lengths = list(map(len, strings))
    return lengths, max(lengths)

dum = ['flower','show', 'bl']
longest_store, max_len = longest_common_prefix(dum)
print(longestStore)
print(max_len)
```